# Using realm in the main app and a library

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to use Realm in a library and in the main app and it keeps complaining that the models in the main app are not part of the schema. I've basically implemented everything in a similar manner to the example provided by Realm https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample and I've got exactly the same issue.

Error:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: class package.models.User is not part of the schema for this Realm.
at io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.getMissingProxyClassException(RealmProxyMediator.java:241)
at io.realm.RealmModuleMediator.getTableName(RealmModuleMediator.java:107)
at io.realm.RealmSchema.getTable(RealmSchema.java:296)
at io.realm.Realm.checkHasPrimaryKey(Realm.java:1469)
at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:902)
```

The error is triggered as soon as I try to save something to Realm - i.e. after log in I'm trying to save the user's details and it crashes.

In my application class for the main app I've got this code

```
   @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES, 0);

    instance = this;

    // initialisations
    Realm.init(this);
    config = new AppConfig(mPrefs);

    this.realm = Realm.getInstance(getRealmConfig());
}

public Realm getLibraryRealm(Object module, String name){
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(name)
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .modules(module)
            .build();
    return Realm.getInstance(config);
}

public RealmConfiguration getRealmConfig(){
    return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(getPackageName())
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .modules(new RealmModule())
            .build();
}
```

Then in the library I try to get a Realm instance as follows:

```
 AppDataAccessor app = (AppDataAccessor) getApplication();
 Realm realm = app.getRealm(new RealmModule(), Constants.REALM_NAME);
```

Worth mentioning that AppDataAccessor is an interface which is implemented by my application class.

Also, both the main app and the library have Realm Modules defined as follows:

```
@io.realm.annotations.RealmModule(library = true, classes = { DataSet.class, Field.class, Form.class })
public class RealmModule {
}
```

and for the main app:

```
@io.realm.annotations.RealmModule(classes = {Notification.class, User.class})
public class RealmModule {
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like `new RealmModule()` in `getRealmConfig` picks the library module. Did you try to use full package name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem this morning.

I was defining a RealmModule for the main app and for the library. It's only necessary for the library.

Answer (score 1):

For **app module** please use `Realm.getDefaultModule()` and for other modules/library just use the custom realm model just like you `RealmModule` class.